# what is the difference between named_scope and method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope, ruby-on-rails-2

named_scope or scope how difference with class method.

```
named_scope :active, :conditions => {:status => 'Active'}

def self.active
  self.find(:all, :conditions => {:status => 'Active'}
end
```

Whats the difference between the two?

Comment: I what language is that?

Answer (score 4):

In the end 'scope' will define a chainable class method on your model. That's why every class method, that returns a 'scope' (which is an object of the class ActiveRecord::Relation) can be used in the same way a definied scope / named_scope can.

If you want to find our more about scopes, I recommend using the rails console to play a bit with the ouput, or - maybe as a start - read the rails guides - they pretty much  explain it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

edit:

Oh, and of course reading into the rails code can often clear up things quicker, then anyone or anything else. If you look at  the definition of the 'scope' method here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L159 you will see, how it's defining a method (on class level) - which is pretty similar to defining the method yourself, as in your example.

Answer (score 2):

The big difference is chainability. Let's say you have another named scope, popular:

```
named_scope :popular, :conditions => { :popular => true }
```

Let's say you want to get popular active users. So you say `User.popular.active`

```
named_scope :active, :conditions => {:status => 'Active'}
```

In this case, then `User.popular.active` works.

On the other hand,

```
def self.active
  self.find(:all, :conditions => {:status => 'Active'}
end
```

may allow you to say `User.active.popular` (depending on your rails version, IIRC), but definitely *not* `User.popular.active`.

Informally, the `scope` method arranges for the method it's defining to be available on other scopes of the object. Defining a class method does not.

Comment: "may allow you to say User.active.popular (depending on your rails version, IIRC), but definitely not User.popular.active." Are the results different?

Comment: Only if you're being affected by a hilariously awful bug, Ayrad.