# write controllers code in model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `ConversionRate` model

```
class ConversionRate < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I want to move to model my controller method `find_something`

```
class ConversionRatesController < ActionController::Base
  #....
  def find_something (param)
    rate = ConversionRate.where(:param=> param)
  end
 end
```

How do I do this? I am thinking of something like this

```
class ConversionRate < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.find_something(param)
   return self.where(:param=> param)
end
```

Comment: You can directly call .where method on model. Why again you are defining a method for it?

Comment: @user2950593 if the answer was fine, you can close this question by choosing it. If you have any further doubt, please comment

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have already found your solution:

```
class ConversionRate < ActiveRecord::Base
 class << self
    def find_something(param)
     where(:param=> param)
    end
  end
end
```

An alternative could be to use a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
class ConversionRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :find_something, ->(param) { where(param: param) }
end
```

Then you can call it from the controller like `ConversionRate.find_something(params)`

I would encourage the first approach if you need to perform some validation on your `param`, otherwise the second is very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! another quetion: how do I define method for instance of model? For example I have `cr= ConversionRate.new;  cr.param = "123"; I want to write cr.find_another_param`

Comment: Or `def self.find_something(param)`

Comment: I guess that this is another question.. it would be a little confusing to add to the same answer. You can close this one and open another to keep the topic distinguished

Comment: @mabe02 - what's the advantage of the singleton method, rather than using a standard class method (i.e. @mahemoff's `def self.find_something `) or your scope? Asking out of curiosity.... not suggesting you're wrong or anything.

Comment: this pretty outdated answer provides a good overview https://stackoverflow.com/a/11816412/5687152 With `scope` you return a subset of an ActiveRecord::Relation, with a self.something method you can return what you prefer. I prefer to enclose class methods inside `class << self ; end` for clarity, but there is no difference with several `def self.something; end`

Comment: `class << self` can be useful if you want to group several class methods together. (I do find Ruby's `class <<` syntax conceptually weird and confusing though, just my opinion.)

Comment: @user2950593 can we consider your problem solved? In case, you can tick this answer